# About Non-blocking I/O is mean server side NIO?(in spring integration docs)

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-ip

I'm working with spring integration.
In this link [About Non-blocking I/O](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#note-nio), is it talking about server side NIO?

I'm using TcpNioClientConnectionFactory(single-use = true) with CachingClientConnectionFactory. that document make me confused.

Answer (score 0):

It applies to both the client and server sides.

Why the confusion? We read and write on both sides.

Without NIO, on the client side with single use, a new thread will be started and stopped for each request/reply; with NIO a pool of threads is used.